# Google App Engine Template Not Found

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've written a lightweight application for Google App Engine in Python 2.5 using webapp.

After I migrated it to Python 2.7, I caught TemplateDoesNotExist error:
    TemplateDoesNotExist: ../../base.html

I'm heard of that relative import of template is forbidden.

1. Is it enough to make template imports absolute?
2. If yes, how to do it?

When I searched for this problem I saw many Django articles, but I'm not using it except webapp.template.

My project structure is like this (though I understand it's not good).

```
src/
  - template/
    - base.html
    - foo/
      - foo.html      (imports base.html)
      - bar/
        - foobar.html (imports ../foo.html)
        - bar.html    (imports ../../base.html)
 - main.py   (imports the following; app = WSGIApplication(...))
 - foo.py    (defines class Foo    which uses foo.html) 
 - bar.py    (defines class Bar    which uses bar.html)
 - foobar.py (defines class FooBar which uses foobar.html)
```

Comment: Any solution found for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: First, I would say upgrade to webapp2 not webapp. Can you post your app.yaml file and the relevant request handlers? I suspect the problem is in the routing to the static file (template).